# Do fsnotify really need global list scan?

Tags: linux, performance, coding-style, notifications, linux-kernel

I'm studying the linux kernel code, more specifically the filesystem notifications within fs/notify/fsnotify.c ... AFAIK, each inode is now given a list of "marks", each one referencing a "group" which listens to notification on that inode. In the VFS code, notifications are raised through the use of `fsnotify(triggering_inode, REASON|OTHER_REASON, additional_parameters...)`

Within that `fsnotify()` function, I'm puzzled by

```
 list_for_each_entry_rcu(group, &fsnotify_groups, group_list) {
     if (test_mask & group->mask) {
        if (!group->ops->should_send_event(group, to_tell, mask))
                continue;
            // more code that sends notification
     }
 }
```

Especially, by the fact that `fsnotify_groups` is obviously (fsnotify.h) a global list where all the groups are recorded. My best bet is that kernel developers know what they're doing here, and that I miss a critical point that prevent us from just using `foreach(mark:inode->fsnotify_mark_entry) { g=mark->associated_group; }` that would definitely scale better with the numbers of notification listeners on the system.

Anybody around has a clue why things still use the global list here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [latest version](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.0/fs/notify/fsnotify.c#L201) doesn't seem to do that anymore.

Comment: so this performance issue has been dealt with since 2.6.36 and the above oddity is just "transitional" poor code.